# Convert ppt to video using python in ubuntu environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-pptx

I have wrote a python script to convert ppt to video using pywin32 which is working fine but when i try to import my script on Ubuntu environment pywin32 doesn't work as its windows supported module.
So i am trying to find something which can convert ppt to video using python in Ubuntu environment.

These is the script which works fine in windows.

```
import win32com.client
import time
import os
ppSaveAsWMV = 37
def cover_ppt_to_wmv(ppt_src,wmv_target):
    ppt = win32com.client.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
    presentation = ppt.Presentations.Open(ppt_src,WithWindow=False)
    presentation.CreateVideo(wmv_target,-1,4,720,24,60)
    start_time_stamp = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        try:
            os.rename(wmv_target,wmv_target)
            print('success')
            break
        except Exception:
            pass
    end_time_stamp=time.time()
    print(end_time_stamp-start_time_stamp)
    ppt.Quit()
    pass
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cover_ppt_to_wmv('','')
```